# Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 171 MB after servicing 0 requests total

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I was getting the following error while loading the data to Google Cloud Storage.

I found couple of posts for the same but want to find where the memory leak is happening. Please let me know how to find.

Error Message:

```
Exceeded soft private memory limit of 128 MB with 171 MB after servicing 0 requests total
```

Code:

```
def download_files(service, report_id, report_fragment):
  """Generate and print sample report.

  Args:
    service: An authorized Doublelcicksearch service.
    report_id: The ID DS has assigned to a report.
    report_fragment: The 0-based index of the file fragment from the files array.
  """
  print "Enter into download_files", report_id
  filename="/xyz/DoubleClickSearch_Campaign"+report_id+"_"+report_fragment+".csv"
  bucket_name="awstogcs"
  fname="DoubleClickSearch_Campaign11212"
  write_retry_params = _gcs.RetryParams(backoff_factor=1.1)
  gcs_file=_gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type='text/plain',retry_params=write_retry_params)
  request = service.reports().getFile(reportId=report_id, reportFragment=report_fragment)
  gcs_file.write(request.execute())
  gcs_file.close()
```

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tracking down memory leak in Google App Engine Golang application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38781096/tracking-down-memory-leak-in-google-app-engine-golang-application)

Comment: `after servicing 0 requests total` - that could indicate that the instance class you configured (or the default you have) may not have sufficient memory for your application, try configuring an instance class with more memory.

Comment: Look for `instance_class` in the [app.yaml syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#syntax). Also see [Instance classes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes)

Comment: @Dan - Actually I am writing a file to Google Cloud Storage. Guessing, it is writing everything into memory and then copying to GCS. Because of that am I getting this error. I have given above code for writing file to GCS.  Actually I need to write Bigger files to GCS so thought of checking.

Comment: @Dan - Do I need to write data to GCS chunk by chunk to avoid the memory issue or this memory issue is totally different.

Comment: Can't really say. Try to write a small chunk, if that works then indeed writing a single chunk is most likely the problem. In general I'd always go for chunk-by-chunk unless I know *for sure* that the max chunk size works well. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201283/google-app-engine-how-to-write-large-files-to-google-cloud-storage

Comment: Thanks Dan for your reply. Do I need to use blobstorage in-order to write chunk by chunk without that cant I write to GCS chunk by chunk.

Comment: No, that's just on the read side in that particular example - your concern is on the write side, so just look at that portion.

Comment: Dan - In the above link this is the code it was used to write into GCS and it uses blobstorage. PATH = '/gs/backupbucket/'
for df in DocumentFile.all():           
  fn = df.blob.filename
  br = blobstore.BlobReader(df.blob)
  write_path = files.gs.create(self.PATH+fn.encode('utf-8'), mime_type='application/zip',acl='project-private') 
  with files.open(write_path, 'a') as fp:
    for buf in iter_blobstore(df.blob):
      try:
        fp.write(buf)
      except files.FileNotOpenedError:
        pass
  files.finalize(write_path)

Comment: `fp.write(buf)` is what you care about - make sure your data to write is split into small enough `buf` pieces to prevent running out of memory for the instance class you chose.